# Can we make this Question a Community Wiki Question?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, community-wiki

I recently asked for [domain language dictionaries](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/2000/139). As it forces the answers to be a big list with one answer for a specific domain and there is no objective best answer, thus it should be a community wiki question.

Can we make this Question a Community Wiki Question?

Comment: @reg a bit more guidance on community wiki http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/the-future-of-community-wiki/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Done. By the way, just use the flagging system for this. "Flag" → "it needs ♦ moderator attention" → "other" → ask for conversion to CW.

Comment: I've never had to suggest something like that to an own question. Next time I'll do it that way.